# Benefits of using aggressive timeouts with reactive programming

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2, project-reactor

In the blocking world, it is highly recommended to set aggressive timeouts in order to fail fast and release the underlying resources (Section 5.1 of https://pragprog.com/book/mnee/release-it).

In the async/non-blocking world, requests are not blocking the main thread and the resources are available immediately for further processing. Timeouts are still necessary, however does it still make sense to set aggressive values?

Comment: Timeouts are needed regardless. For instance, let's assume you are doing something in the network; it doesn't matter if it's asynchronous and non-blocking, you will never know the outcome...so you would like to have a window established where things are considered successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

In real-time software, network requests or control operations on machinery take a large amount of time in comparison to day-to-day software operations. For instance, telling a step motor to advance to a particular position may take seconds, while normal operations might take milliseconds. Let's say that a typical step motor advance takes `n` milliseconds, and one that goes the maximum distance takes `m` milliseconds.

An aggressive timeout would compute `n` and add a small fudge factor, perhaps 10%, and fail quickly if the goal wasn't reached in that time. As you stated, the aggressive timeout will allow you to release resources. A non-aggressive timeout of `m` plus `epsilon` would fail much more slowly, and tie up resources unnecessarily.

In the asynchronous software world, there a number of other choices between success and failure. An asynchronous operation might also calculate `n` plus 10%, and put up a progress bar (if user feedback is desired) and then show progress towards the estimated goal's end. When the timeout is reached, the progress bar would be full, but you might cause it to pulse or change color to indicate it was taking longer than expected. If the step motor still had not reached its goal after `m` milliseconds, then you could announce a failure.

In other cases, when the feedback is not important, then you could certainly use `m` plus `epsilon` as your timeout.